# Three.js - How to make viewport circular?

Tags: three.js

let's take this example.
https://codepen.io/jdrew1303/pen/poyVOyG

```
renderer.setScissor(left, positiveYUpBottom, width, height);
renderer.setViewport(left, positiveYUpBottom, width, height);
```

I have something similar using scissor and viewport. this works fine, but I need the "view1" to be rounded, instead of rectangular(imagine a compass in a videogame). Using css border-radius obviously doesnt work.

Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT: the reason I cant use border-radius in the original canvas is because it would affect the entire view. I just need the specified viewport/scissor to be rounded but not the rest of the view

Comment: Why doesn't CSS border radius work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to solve my problem using a second canvas and giving that second canvas a CSS boder-radius and positioning it on the screen where I needed.

something like:

```
destCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```